# How to convert data type (dd:hh:mm:ss) "1 day, 01:00:00" in seconds using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert data like: "1 day, 01:00:00"  in seconds, using these lines of code:

```
import datetime

time_1 = '1 day, 01:00:00'

h, m, s = str(time_1).split(':')
seconds = (int(datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s)).total_seconds()))
print(seconds)
```

But I got this error:

```
>>> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 day, 01'
```

I can get correct result deleting '1 day, ' from the variable "time_1", but not including the days...

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your time string with `re`:

```
import datetime
import re

time_1 = '1 day, 01:00:00'

for (days, t) in re.findall(r'(?:(\d+)\s+days?)?,?\s*([\d:]+)', time_1):
    h, m, s = str(t).split(':')
    seconds = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s)).total_seconds()
    if days:
        seconds = seconds + datetime.timedelta(days=int(days)).total_seconds()
    print(int(seconds))
```

Prints:

```
90000
```

Answer (score 1):

Before splitting by ":", you need to split by the comma and take the trailing part,
if you don't do this then `h` will be set to `"1 day, 01"`

```py
time_aux = time_1.split(',')[1]
h, m, s = time_aux.split(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

Split up your initial string using split

```
result = [x.strip() for x in time.split(',')]
```

Then take the first item and the first character and multiply it by 64200 to convert it to seconds, then just convert the hours, minutes and seconds like you have.

```
seconds = (int(datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s)).total_seconds()))
total_seconds = int(result[0][1])*64200 + seconds
```